# WireGuard & UFW : UFW blocks traffic on wg0, even if a rule allows it

Tags: debian, ufw, wireguard

I run Wireguard on Debian with the additional interface `wg0`. With this ufw rule, I would expect that ufw would pass my traffic:

```
ufw allow in on wg0 to any
```

But instead, ufw is blocking the traffic:

```
[14674.950320] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wg0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=10.0.0.2 DST=54.xx.xx.xx LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=54263 DPT=443 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[14675.451891] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wg0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=fd00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 DST=2a05:xxx LEN=84 TC=0
```

Has anyone an idea whats going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The log shows two interfaces: `IN=wg0 OUT=eth0`. That means it's routed/forwarded traffic and not traffic with the node as destination, where `OUT=` would be empty. It translates in the backend (`iptables`) to the `filter/FORWARD` chain instead of the `filter/INPUT` chain.

The [UFW syntax](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/ufw/ufw.8#ufw%7E9) to control routed traffic is:

> ```
> ufw [--dry-run] route [delete] [insert NUM] [prepend] allow|deny|reject|limit [in|out on INTERFACE] [log|log-all]
> ```

(not clearly apparent, but both `in` and `out` can be used at the same time)

So to allow the traffic that was blocked in OP's case:

```
ufw route allow in on wg0 out on eth0
```

or for any forwarded traffic coming from `wg0` whatever the destination interface, just:

```
ufw route allow in on wg0
```

Comment: Thank you @A.B! ``ufw route allow in on wg0`` did the trick for me!